# Create Jquery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I creating jquery Plugin with simple alert option. I did this way see below is my code.But it doesn't work.
    **Below code is the seperate js file.**

```
(function($) {
        $.fn.gettingmessage = function() {

            var element = this;

            $(element).load(function() {

                alertingcontent();

                function preventnextpage() {
                    return false;
                }

                function alertingcontent() {
                    alert("nicely done");
            });
        };

    })(jQuery);
```

**I called this function as
this way**

```
     $(function(){  
  $("body").gettingmessage();  
});
```

I am not sure how can i fix this any suggestion would be great.
**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vicky081/WTNLq/1/)**

Thanks

Comment: *"`var element = this;`"* In the plug-in, `this` is not an element. It's the jQuery *set*, which may have zero or more elements in it. It doesn't really matter much in the code you've shown above; it would if you did anything non-trivial.

Comment: *"But it doesn't work"* "Doesn't work" is not a useful problem description. Doesn't work *how*? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead? What errors do you see in the console? (Or if none, that's useful information.)

Comment: The first problem is that you forgot to close the body of the `alertingcontent` function. Use firebug/developer tools to catch simple syntax errors like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- First, you're missing a closing bracket.
- Second, the [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) function doesn't do what you're searching for, use [`ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) instead of.

Updated code :

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.gettingmessage = function() {

        var element = this;

        $(element).ready(function() {

            alertingcontent();

            function preventnextpage() {
                return false;
            }

            function alertingcontent() {
                alert("nicely done");
            }
        });
    };

})(jQuery);

$(function(){  
  $("body").gettingmessage();  
});
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/WTNLq/4/)

Comment: AFAIK, `ready()` is only bound to `document` to check when the DOM is ready. There is nothing wrong with the `load` event here (which takes images in to consideration as well, which `ready` does not).

Comment: I guess the problem is `load()` is bound to `body`, which is already loaded when the javascript is executed.

Comment: It depends on whether if all resources in `body` are loaded. Consider `$(window).load` vs `$(document).ready`

Comment: Hi one quick question @zessx It works great, but when i adding that function with id is not working ? See I changed the div as different id calling jquery function is different id but still i get alert.http://jsfiddle.net/vicky081/WTNLq/10/